# Pandas - как отфильтровать DataFrame по значению,присутствующему в другом DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, запрос, dataframe

Задача. Есть два DataFrame. В одном список того, что нас интересует, в другом - некоторые операционные данные, возможно содержащие интересующие нас строки:

```
import pandas as pd    
df_report = pd.DataFrame({'key':["a01","a02","b07"], 'lookup':[True,False,True]})
df_work = pd.DataFrame({'key':["a01","a01","b03","a01","a01","a01"], 
                            'category':["good","good","broken","good","broken","good"], 
                            'quantity':[3,2,1,1,2,5],
                           })
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns = df_work.columns, data = None)
for key in set(df_report['key']):
    slice = df_work[df_work['key']==key]
    if not slice.empty:        
        df_result = df_result.append(slice, ignore_index=True) 
df_result
```

выдает желаемое:

```
   key  category quantity    
0 a01    good       3
1 a01    good       2
2 a01    good       1
3 a01   broken      2
4 a01    good       5
```

то есть я хочу получить DataFrame, в котором есть только те строки `df_work`, поле `key` в которых встречается в поле `key` из `df_report`.

Весь этот огород я написал, т.к.

```
df_work.query('"key" in df_report["key"]')
```

выдает ошибку `UndefinedVariableError: name 'df_report' is not defined`.
Есть более изящный способ отфильтровать DataFrame желаемым образом за пару строк?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью метода [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df_work[df_work.key.isin(df_report.key)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

С помощью [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) (переменные обозначаются знаком `@`):

```
df_work.query("key in @df_report.key").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: ! Забавно. в Документации написано, что конструкция .query(... in  ...) как раз призвана заменить конструкцию isin на более изящную.... т.к. она не заработала, я даже не стал пробовать "isin".      
Благодарю. Возможно это - решение, если не подоспеет более "изящное".
Могли бы вы объяснить  -  отчего мой вариант не работает?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Я написал то, что первое в голову пришло. Сейчас почитал про query. Обновил ответ. Действительно, так короче. А не работало, видимо, потому, что переменные внутри выражения нужно обозначать "@".

Comment: Утверждается что на больших фреймах query быстрее

Comment: Ага, пишут: "The main reason why NumExpr achieves better performance than NumPy is that it avoids allocating memory for intermediate results. This results in better cache utilization and reduces memory access in general. Due to this, NumExpr works best with large arrays."

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае можно также воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In [51]: df_work.merge(df_report[['key']])
Out[51]:
   key category  quantity
0  a01     good         3
1  a01     good         2
2  a01     good         1
3  a01   broken         2
4  a01     good         5
```

PS [@Andrey указал в своем ответе наиболее идиоматичные решения для данного вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/955085/211923)